# Runtime how to determine Debug or release mode in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, macros, release

I am doing my school assignment. During debug mode I would like to turn on my console mode and during release turn off console.

I have try marco as recommended in stackoverflow but it is not working. I am using visual studio 2012 (empty project c++)

```
#if DEBUG
 //doing something
#else
 //Release mode doing something
#endif
```

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting a compile time error?  Does it doe the same thing for either a release or a debug build? What?

Comment: Not sure why. Inside my DEBUG what include is   if(AllocConsole())
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

Comment: I dont have any compile time error. Do I have to set any properties inside visual project or something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`#if DEBUG` will only work if you define `DEBUG` via the compiler options.

By default, `DEBUG` is not defined, but `_DEBUG` is.  Try `#if defined(_DEBUG)`, or change your compiler options (via Project Properties / Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Preprocessor / Preprocessor Definitions) to define `DEBUG`.

Comment: Hi, I have tried defined(_DEBUG) but it still not working. #if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)

Comment: Could you explain a bit detail regard to configuration properties. I try to put DEBUG wont it work

Comment: What i could think of is DEBUG= 1; under the configuration properties. Not sure is the correct way to do it

Comment: @user2306421: It's still not really clear where your problem is - are you 100% sure it's with the `#if`?  Try putting a `#error` in the `#if` and `#else` blocks, and see what output you get from the compiler.

Comment: @user2306421: `#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)` needs a double-bar: `#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)`

Answer (score 1):

`#if DEBUG` will resolve itself at compile time not at run time.

`NDEBUG` is pretty standard macro defined in release mode. 
And I think Visual studio defines `_DEBUG` macro when in debug mode.

In any case you can define your own macros in Visual Studio

Go to `Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions` There you can add macros for your project in the build configuration you have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems that tproblem you're running into is getting a console window open and connected to `stdout` (having little to do with DEBUG vs. RELEASE builds).

See the MS Support Article [INFO: Calling CRT Output Routines from a GUI Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105305/en-us) for a working example of how to have a GUI program open a console and direct `stdout` to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// ...

int hCrt;
FILE *hf;

AllocConsole();
hCrt = _open_osfhandle(
    (long) GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
    _O_TEXT
    );
hf = _fdopen( hCrt, "w" );
*stdout = *hf;
int i = setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
puts("hello world");
```

Actually, on further testing, your simpler technique of using `freopen("CONOUT$","w",stdout);` works too.  For some reason in my initial tests it didn't seem to work. You may need to also have the `setvbuf()` call to avoid buffering problems.

Comment: Thanks MichaelBurr for telling me about the buffer issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Visual studio 2019:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
// do something in a debug build
#else
// do something in a release build
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

For C# the constants DEBUG works fine, Just make sure that in the project properties it is enabled.

Go to project properties (by right clicking on your project in solution explorer), then select build option on right side of the window and check the define DEBUG constant checkbox.

Then you can use code like this.

```
#if DEBUG

// debug mode

#else

//release mode

#endif
```

Comment: Where does c# come into this?