# Why is my VS Code debugger bouncing around my C++ code?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I run my debugger, stop at a breakpoint, then try to step through my code. But the debugger will often skip lines and/or jump back to previous lines unexpectedly, and even go over the same line multiple times. Some of my coworkers have also experienced this problem and no one knows why.

Using Visual Studio Code v1.39.2

Comment: Are you debugging optimized code?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I find out?

Comment: What compiler flags do you use?

Comment: Could also be inlined functions as well.

Comment: For example, if you have a function with multiple `return` statements, the debugger may jump to the last one (due to optimizations).

Comment: Print out an assembly language listing of the function to find the truth (as to whether your code is optimized or not).

Comment: The debugger bounces in functions with multiple return statements as well as ones with a single return.

Comment: Is your application single threaded or are there multiple threads? Visual studio shows which thread is being used, and changes the arrow if the thread is different from the previous step

Comment: @Rhombus This doesn't have anything to do with VSCode. How do you compile your code? What compiler do you use, and with what flags?

Comment: @ Tas Single threaded @ HolyBlackCat I'm not sure I will have to investigate

Comment: Are you debugging in _Debug_ configuration or _Release_ (similar question to "are you debugging optimised code"). _Release_ is typically optimised

Comment: You're clearly trying to debug the Release build.

Answer (score 2):

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16142736/12416726). I determined that the debugger is bouncing because I am in the release build, which according to [user Tas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831561/why-is-my-vs-code-debugger-bouncing-around-my-c-code?noredirect=1#comment105800031_59831561) is typically optimized.